# pandas get permutations of column values based on another column

Tags: python, permutation

I am trying to calculate every possible permutation of ballot1 and ballot2. In this case I can write a solution manually, but is there a more "pythonic" way?

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

d = {'vote': [1,2,3,55],
     'ballot1': [1,0,1,-1],
     'ballot2': [0,1,-1,-1]
    }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Example solution. The order doesnt matter, as long as every combination of ballot 1 and 2 is checked for all values of -1,0,1:

```
print(stats.f_oneway(df1[df1['ballot1']==1]['vote'],df1[df1['ballot1']==0]['vote']))
print(stats.f_oneway(df1[df1['ballot1']==1]['vote'],df1[df1['ballot1']==-1]['vote']))
print(stats.f_oneway(df1[df1['ballot1']==0]['vote'],df1[df1['ballot1']==-1]['vote']))

print(stats.f_oneway(df1[df1['ballot2']==1]['vote'],df1[df1['ballot2']==0]['vote']))
print(stats.f_oneway(df1[df1['ballot2']==1]['vote'],df1[df1['ballot2']==-1]['vote']))
print(stats.f_oneway(df1[df1['ballot2']==0]['vote'],df1[df1['ballot2']==-1]['vote']))

print(stats.f_oneway(df1[df1['ballot2']==1]['vote'],df1[df1['ballot1']==0]['vote']))
print(stats.f_oneway(df1[df1['ballot2']==1]['vote'],df1[df1['ballot1']==-1]['vote']))
print(stats.f_oneway(df1[df1['ballot2']==0]['vote'],df1[df1['ballot1']==-1]['vote']))

print(stats.f_oneway(df1[df1['ballot1']==1]['vote'],df1[df1['ballot2']==0]['vote']))
print(stats.f_oneway(df1[df1['ballot1']==1]['vote'],df1[df1['ballot2']==-1]['vote']))
print(stats.f_oneway(df1[df1['ballot1']==0]['vote'],df1[df1['ballot2']==-1]['vote']))
```

Comment: In your result you have ballot2 = 1 & ballot2 = 0 simultaneously. Is this what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are looking for the Cartesian product of 2 lists. This is possible via `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

d = {'vote': [1,2,3,55],
     'ballot1': [1,0,1,-1],
     'ballot2': [0,1,-1,-1]
    }

for i in product(set(d['ballot1']), set(d['ballot2'])):
    print(i)

# (0, 0)
# (0, 1)
# (0, -1)
# (1, 0)
# (1, 1)
# (1, -1)
# (-1, 0)
# (-1, 1)
# (-1, -1)
```